# Temp table throws invalid object name after adding 'SET SHOWPLAN_ALL' Sql Server MS17

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm fairly new to SQL Server and I've been assigned the task of optimizing some SQL Queries generated by a CMS.  After I add the code

```
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
GO;
```

and execute the query, the local temp table #tempSecondLevel throws an 'invalid object name' exception in my INSERT INTO statement.  You will see a SELECT INTO #tmpSecondLevel statement and then an INSERT INTO #tmpSecondLevel statement.  The next statements are for #tmpFirstLevel, and I'm not sure if those are relevant to this question.

```
use Kentico8_2;
go
set showplan_all on;
go

-- Write revised query here.
DECLARE @ProductNodeGuid uniqueidentifier = '6F6F733D-AE4F-47DC-9BE9-52B967E9F41D'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpSecondLevel') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpSecondLevel

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpFirstLevel') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpFirstLevel

-- Get all of the items(that go on the secondLevel) that go underneath a heading(on the firstLevel)
-- Get all of the materials that belong to this node that go on the second level
SELECT
     NodeLevel = 1
    ,NodeParentID = CASE WHEN MaterialTypeSelectByMaterial = 0 THEN M.NodeID ELSE M.NodeParentID END
    ,M.NodeID
    ,M.MaterialName
    ,MaterialImage = MV.MaterialVariantImage
    ,M.NodeAliasPath
    ,M.Published
    ,M.NodeGUID
    ,M.ClassName
    ,M.NodeOrder
INTO 
    #tmpSecondLevel
FROM 
    View_NOF_Material_Joined M
    JOIN View_NOF_Product_Joined P
        ON P.ProductMaterialNodeGuidList LIKE '%' + CONVERT(nvarchar(36), M.NodeGUID) + '%'
    JOIN View_NOF_MaterialType_Joined MT
        ON MT.NodeID = M.NodeParentID
    LEFT JOIN View_NOF_MaterialVariant_Joined MV
        ON MV.NodeParentID = M.NodeID AND MV.NodeOrder = 1 -- always the first
WHERE
    P.NodeGUID = @ProductNodeGuid AND MaterialTypeSelectByMaterial = 1

-- Get all of the material variants that belong to this node that go on the second level
INSERT INTO
    #tmpSecondLevel
SELECT
     NodeLevel = 1
    ,NodeParentID = CASE WHEN MaterialTypeSelectByMaterial = 0 THEN M.NodeID ELSE M.NodeParentID END
    ,MV.NodeID
    ,MaterialName = MV.MaterialVariantName
    ,MaterialImage = MV.MaterialVariantImage
    ,MV.NodeAliasPath
    ,MV.Published
    ,MV.NodeGUID
    ,MV.ClassName
    ,MV.NodeOrder
FROM 
    View_NOF_MaterialVariant_Joined MV
    JOIN View_NOF_Product_Joined P 
        ON P.ProductMaterialNodeGuidList LIKE '%' + CONVERT(nvarchar(36), MV.NodeGUID) + '%'
    JOIN View_NOF_Material_Joined M 
        ON M.NodeID = MV.NodeParentID
    JOIN View_NOF_MaterialType_Joined MT 
        ON MT.NodeID = M.NodeParentID
WHERE 
    P.NodeGUID = @ProductNodeGuid 
        AND MaterialTypeSelectByMaterial = 0

-- Get all of the headings( for the firstLevel) that go above a list of items(on the secondLevel)
-- Get all of the material types that are used as headings
SELECT DISTINCT
     NodeLevel = 0
    ,NodeParentID = NULL
    ,MT.NodeID
    ,MaterialName = MT.MaterialTypeName
    ,MaterialImage = ''
    ,MT.NodeAliasPath
    ,MT.Published
    ,MT.NodeGUID
    ,MT.ClassName
    ,MT.NodeOrder
INTO 
    #tmpFirstLevel
FROM 
    View_NOF_MaterialType_Joined MT
    INNER JOIN #tmpSecondLevel M 
        ON MT.NodeID = M.NodeParentID

-- Get all of the materials that are used as headings
INSERT INTO 
    #tmpFirstLevel
SELECT DISTINCT
     NodeLevel = 0
    ,NodeParentID = NULL
    ,MJ.NodeID
    ,MaterialName = MJ.MaterialName
    ,MaterialImage = ''
    ,MJ.NodeAliasPath
    ,MJ.Published
    ,MJ.NodeGUID
    ,MJ.ClassName
    ,MTJ.NodeOrder
FROM 
    View_NOF_Material_Joined MJ
    INNER JOIN View_NOF_MaterialType_Joined MTJ 
        ON MTJ.NodeID = MJ.NodeParentID
    INNER JOIN #tmpSecondLevel M 
        ON MJ.NodeID = M.NodeParentID

-- Put all of the second level items (the details) and first level items (the headings) in the same table
SELECT * FROM #tmpSecondLevel
UNION
SELECT * FROM #tmpFirstLevel
ORDER BY NodeOrder

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpSecondLevel') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpSecondLevel

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpFirstLevel') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpFirstLevel
```

I predict this is a simple question to ask since I only added two lines of code, but the help is much appreciated.  If you have any tips for me about optimizing these queries, that is greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using `SELECT * INTO #tmpFirstLevel` then `INSERT INTO #tmpFirstLevel`, can you please try `CREATE TABLE #tmpFirstLevel` first and `INSERT INTO #tmpFirstLevel` with the logical blocks.

Comment: Yes, I had that in mind when I started.  It's good to be specific!  Thanks for the input @Arulkumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because SET SHOWPLAN_ALL is the command to show Estimated execution plans.  Therefore no TSQL commands are actually executed, and thus the #tmpSecondLevel table is never created.  So you get an error.  This would be the same thing as clicking the "Display Estimated Execution Plan" in SSMS.

You can read about that command here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-showplan-all-transact-sql

If you want to show the Actual execution replace SHOWPLAN_ALL line with SET STATISTICS XML ON.  This will display the actual execution plan when you run the query.